# Wrong offsetX and offsetY on mousedown event of parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I facing a problem while getting offsetX on mousedown. Here is my code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="myP" onmousedown="mouseDown()">
            Click the text! The mouseDown() function is triggered when the mouse button is pressed down over this paragraph,
            <p style="margin-left:50px">
             and sets the color of the text to red. The mouseUp() function is triggered when the mouse button is released, 
            </p>
            and sets the color of the text to green.
        </div>
        <script>
            function mouseDown() {
                var left = event.offsetX;
                var top = event.offsetY;
                console.log(top+"::"+left);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am getting correct result which i want when my mousedown is upon the div area but it gives me wrong result when my mouse is over the paragraph area. I could not understand why this is happens because event is of parent element which is DIV element.

Obtain Result
Case 1: when my mouse is over DIV Element
        top: 17px,  left: 61px

Case 1: when my mouse is over DIV Element
        top: 11px,  left: 9px

Answer (score 31):

The **MouseEvent.offsetX** or **MouseEvent.offsetY** will give you the coordinates of the mouse pointer relative to the target nodes padding edge.

> [**MouseEvent.offsetX**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX)
>
> The MouseEvent.offsetX read-only property provides the offset in the X coordinate of the mouse pointer between that event and the padding edge of the **target node**.

So in the case of the `<p>` element inside the `#myP` element you are getting different values for `offsetX` and `offsetY` as expected.

What you could do to always get the mouse coordinates relative to the `#myP` element is to subtract the `left` and `top` values given by `getBoundingClientRect` method from the `MouseEvent.clientX` and `MouseEvent.clientY` properties.

Here is an example.

```js
var myP = document.getElementById('myP'),
    output = document.getElementById('output');

function mouseDown(e) {
  var rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect(),
      offsetX = e.clientX - rect.left,
      offsetY = e.clientY - rect.top;
  output.textContent = "Mouse-X: " + offsetX + ", Mouse-Y: " +  offsetY;
  console.log("Mouse-X: " + offsetX, "Mouse-Y: " + offsetY);
}

myP.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#myP {
  background: lawngreen;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#myP > p {
  background: yellow;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#myP > div > p {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myP">
  Click the text! The mouseDown() function is triggered when the mouse button is pressed down over this paragraph,
  <p>
    andsets the color of the text to red. The mouseUp() function is triggered when the mouse button is released,
  </p>
  <div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut quaerat dolor modi et quidem repudiandae vero, recusandae laborum quae veritatis, doloribus similique accusamus quibusdam voluptate, dolore fugiat eum. Corporis, porro.
    </p>
  </div>
  and sets the color of the text to green.
</div>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: @Kushal Jain This should be marked as the right answer. it worked perfectly for me. Very clever solution.

Answer (score -1):

As a fast solution you can apply `pointer-events: none;` to the root children node

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).