# Why mouseEvent.offset is different for click in the same position

Tags: javascript, css, events

I am wondering why `e.offsetX` and `e.offsetY` are different for clicking in the same place.
For the first click in a button `e.offsetX` and `e.offsetY` are correct but if you click a button before old **ripple** effect diapers than received event has incorrect `e.offsetX` and `e.offsetY` (always around 0). Because of this behavior my **ripple** effect has incorrect position if I click a button quickly many times.

- Why this event has such `e.offsetX` and `e.offsetY` ?
- How can I fix the position of my ripple effect without using `e.target` ?

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const ripple = document.createElement('span');
    ripple.style.left = `${e.offsetX}px`;
    ripple.style.top = `${e.offsetY}px`;
    button.appendChild(ripple);
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        ripple.remove();
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
button {
  overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

button > span {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    animation: ripple 1.0s linear infinite;
}
    
@keyframes ripple {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1000);
    }
}
```

```html
<button>Test</button>
```

for those who prefer more [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kKaczynski/5ktj9eb0/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`offsetX` and `offsetY` returns the position of event on the `currentTarget` not target. So when you click for the second time you are targeting the span you've just created.
What I would have do is add `pointer-events: none` to the span css.

Ther other way is to use `offsetX` [Wrong offsetX and offsetY on mousedown event of parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360704/wrong-offsetx-and-offsety-on-mousedown-event-of-parent-element#answer-35364901)

Comment: I would also consider removing `infinite` from the animation because this is why your ripple effect fires 2 times instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you end up getting the `offset` of the ripple span, rather than the button. Adding a containing div like the below fixes it:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const div = document.querySelector('div');
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const ripple = document.createElement('span');
    ripple.style.left = `${e.offsetX}px`;
    ripple.style.top = `${e.offsetY}px`;
    div.appendChild(ripple);
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        ripple.remove();
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    animation: ripple 0.6s linear infinite;
}
    
@keyframes ripple {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1000);
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
<button>Test</button>
</div>
```